# Self teaching python. Having trouble with score incrementing after each round

Tags: python, python-3.x

TL:DR Trying to set up a scoring system, it doesn't seem to go up when you get than answer right

As the title says I'm teaching myself python, thus this is only the second code I have written (hints in why I'm learning python). I'm more than happy to take criticism on everything from syntax to how to better comment. With that being said, let's get to my issue.

This is a small guessing game. The book I'm reading taught the "for guessTaken" and subsequent code. My problem is in one small aspect of my code. The scoring system won't increment.

I set up the code in the for loop called games then try to have it display at that start of each round and go up with each correct guess. However, it will display 0 for the first few rounds then it will show 2 ( or whatever your current score is I think...). I think the problem is I'm calling the score +1 int in an if statement but I've moved the code around and can't figure it out.

I am aware that it's not beautiful! There are also a few bugs (number of games played isn't what you enter.)Right now I'm only working on the scoring system.

```
         #this is a guess the number game.
    import random

    #Get's user's name
    print("Hello. Welcome to Print's guessing game. Please enter your name: ")
    userName = input()

    #askes if they are ready
    print("Are you ready to play " + userName + "?")
    ready = input().lower()

    if ready == 'yes' :
        print("Let's get started")
    else:
        while ready != 'yes':
            print("Let me know when you are ready")
            ready = input().lower()

                            #Game start


    #number of games       
    games = int(input("How many games would you like to play?"))

    if games >= 1:
        print("Let's get started")


        for games in range (int(games), 1, -1):
            while games != 1:     

                print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20 ")
                secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
                score = 0
                print("Current score: " + str(score))
                print("Debug: " + str(secretNumber))

                for guessTaken in range (7, 1, -1):
                    print("you have " + str(guessTaken - 1 ) + " guesses left")
                    guess = int(input())
                    if guess < secretNumber:
                        print("Your guess is to low. Please guess again")

                    elif guess > secretNumber:
                        print("Your guess is too high. Maybe something a little lower?")

                    else:
                        break # This conditon is for the right guess.



                if guess == secretNumber:
                    print("good Job " + userName + "! you guessed the number right!")
                    score = int(score + 1)
                    print("your score is " + str(score))
                    games = int(games - 1)

                else:
                    print("Nope, the number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber))
                print("you have " + str(games) + " games left")

    elif games == 0:
        while games == 0:
            print("Would you like to exit? Yes or No ")
            exit = input().lower()
            if exit == 'yes':
                quit()
            else:
               games = int(input("How many games would you like to play?"))
    else:
        print("wtf")
```

Comment: Move this ->score = 0 to before for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your score variable is being initialized to zero every time your code goes through the while loop. If you want it to track the total score for all of the games, initialize it right after your `print("Let's get started")`. This will reset their score whenever they tell you how many games they want to play.

If you don't want their score to reset until they quit your program, you will have to initialize it at the beginning of your program. Up by your `import random` would work well.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! It was resting back to 0 because it was after the for loop?

Comment: Your while loop runs until your games variable is equal to 1. That could be a lot of loops depending on your games variable. The problem was that each loop caused your score to be reset to 0. In order to prevent the reset, you have to move the initialization of the score outside of the loops.